# Font-awesome icon hovers separate to text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome icons to accompany list items in a navigation bar like so:

```
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Latest</a>
                </li>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav li a {
    color:#f0f0f0;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color:#7dbd83;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

I've tried a few things such as making a separate CSS only containing i and i:hover and that changes the hover colour independently of the text. I've also tried include i and i:hover in the css below after a but that breaks the effect altogether.

How can I get the icon to change color on hover at the same time as the text?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: It is changing color with text http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/krahhxwp/1/

Comment: Ya...it´s working without .navbar .navbar-nav classes...maybe there is a problem with your classes - http://jsfiddle.net/216n0gxs/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>

 </script>
 <style>

.animate_it{
 color:#f0f0f0;
 -webkit-transition: color 2s;
 -moz-transition: color 2s;
 transition:color 2s;
  }

  .animate_it:hover{
  color:#7dbd83;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s;
  -moz-transition: color 2s;
   transition: color 2s;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
   <body>
               <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#"><i class="animate_it" > Latest</i></a>
                </li>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: just use simple class